Which of this is correct way to add the neutral and ground to the main panel?
I'm very confuse with some videos about how to do the neutral (white) and ground (green).
So my question is which of the following images is the correct way to get neutral and ground for the Main panel?
Or is it that both are correct and Safe to use and it's just a matter of geographical location (different countries)?
First image is using two rods while the second one is using only one rod for neutral and ground
This

Or


Your general location matters.  Different places do things differently, so what is right for me, can be wrong for you.  We use a ground wire from the first/main panel to two ground rods or a UFER ground.

México, basically North America. I'm basically looking to get and answer on the question that even if one of both is used, are both safe?

The normal setup for US and Canada follows. As far as I can tell, Mexico is very similar, using 127/220, which is basically the same as the US 120/208. More common for the US is 120/240, but 120/208 is common enough that most large appliances (water heaters, dryers, air conditioners) can work with 208, and 127 is close enough to 120 that normal 120V appliances will work fine with 127V in Mexico.
The normal setup in the US is:

Meter has hots and neutral only.
The first panel after the meter has hots, neutral and ground, with neutral and ground bonded.

That "first panel" can be:

A physically separate panel, anywhere from a few inches to several feet from the meter.
A physically separate panel a farther distance away but with only a single breaker in a box ("disconnect") near the meter. The disconnect takes care of the safety (you don't want long distances of unprotected wire) while the main panel still does everything else.
A single box that includes both the meter and a main panel - a "meter main".

The ground wire to the ground rods (normally either 2 ground rods several feet apart or a single "ufer ground" in concrete) connects to the main panel, wherever that main panel is located.
In the main panel, you have a neutral bar. You will usually also have a ground bar. Neutral wires can only ever connect to the neutral bar. Ground wires can connect to the ground bar or connect to the neutral bar in a main panel. In a subpanel (any panel fed from the main panel or from another subpanel) the ground wires can only go on the ground bar.
In the main panel, the neutral (normally by way of a screw on the neutral bar) is bonded to the ground. The metal case of the panel is, by definition, connected to the ground, so a screw through the neutral bar to the back of the panel case is all that is needed.
Comparing to the pictures:

The first picture shows two separate ground rods connected together with one wired to the meter and one to the main panel. That is wrong. Instead you run the green ground wire (or bare wire, as is commonly done since the ground rod wire doesn't carry normal current so it is safe to be bare) from the main panel to both ground rods. The wire is normally clamped to the first rod in a way that does not break the wire and the wire then continues to end with a clamp on the second rod. No wire from meter to ground rods.

The second picture shows one ground rod with a wire split to go to both meter and main panel. That is wrong. The wire should be a single wire, no connections in the middle, going directly from the ground rod to the main panel. No wire is needed from meter to ground rod. There should be a second ground rod unless there is an "ufer grund" or (possibly, jurisdiction dependent) a water pipe ground wire connection.


